# migrate from ET.parse to etree.iterparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

Wrote  a code to parse .osm file.
Spend a lot of time to build a  up to 50 rows code but ran into a 'Memory Error' problem.
Seems like the best solution is to use interparse() instead of parse().

**My question is: how should I change my code**
*(strating of my code)*

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.osm')
root = tree.getroot()
```

**to ( using interparse() method)**
*(not my code)*

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
context=etree.iterparse('file.osm', events=('start', 'end', 'start-ns', 'end-ns'))
```

**and not to ruin rest of my code**
*(only part of my code)*

```
list=[]
for i in root.findall('node'):  
    lat=i.get('lat')
    lon=i.get('lon')
    dict = {}
    for ii in i:        
        dict['lat']=lat
        dict['lon']=lon     
        key=ii.get('k')
        val=ii.get('v')     
        dict[key]=val       
    if len(dict)>0:
        list.append(dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tree = ET.iterparse('file.osm')
root = tree.root
```

this will give you the tree root. from there it is the same as parse

Comment: Unfortunanly: **AtributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'interparse'**

Comment: thats because the attribute's name is iterparse and not interparse