# get children between <start> and /<end> nodes using interparse()

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

Have a huge .xml file. Didn't find solution to  [my previos question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339067/migrate-from-et-parse-to-etree-iterparse) Decided to use `interparse()` to get node.
**Problem: can't extract children nodes.**

.xml sample

```
<node id="3828373736" lat="54.6849130" lon="25.2850783" version="1" timestamp="2015-11-10T10:52:34Z" changeset="35211986" uid="1241595" user="Runis">
<tag k="highway" v="traffic_sign"/>
<tag k="traffic_sign" v="LT:552"/>
</node>
<node id="3828373737" lat="54.6848815" lon="25.2851614" version="1" timestamp="2015-11-10T10:52:34Z" changeset="35211986" uid="1241595" user="Runis">
 <tag k="highway" v="traffic_sign"/>
 <tag k="traffic_sign" v="LT:553"/>
</node>
```

Part of my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
file=('file.osm')
context=etree.iterparse(file, events=('start', 'end', 'start-ns', 'end-ns'))

for event, elem in context:
if event == "start" and elem.tag == "node": 
    ID=elem.get('id')
    lat=elem.get('lat')
    lon=elem.get('lon')     
    print ID,lat,lon
    elem.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be that I found the solution. It would be great if you share your ideas how to optimize this code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
file=('filel.osm')
context=etree.iterparse(file)

for event, elem in context: 
if elem.tag == "node":      
    ID=elem.get('id')
    lat=elem.get('lat')
    lon=elem.get('lon') 
    #print ID,lat,lon
    for child in elem:          
        key=child.get('k')
        val=child.get('v')
        print ID,lat,lon,key,val            
        child.clear()
    elem.clear()
```